# nivo-lightbox doesnt want to load lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, nivo-slider

Im trying to get nivo-lightbox to load up as a lightbox, but everytime I click on the image it just opens up the image in the same window.

I even tried using my own image, but still loads it up in the same window

according to jsfiddle, there are no errors, and I followed the documentation word for word

here is a link to take a look.
hopefully someone can figure out what is happening, if need be I can upload my project online and you can take a look at the source code and see why it doesnt want to load.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/jzJKb/3/

HTML

```
<a rel="nivoLightbox" href="http://aetherthemes.com/demo/visia/images/projects/project1-slide2.jpg" title="This is an image title">
<img src="http://aetherthemes.com/demo/visia/images/projects/project1-slide2.jpg" alt="" />
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a').nivoLightbox();});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used nivo lightbox for long, but your script looks like it's targeting anchor tags. Have you tried putting a class or id on your slider images?
Example html:
    `<a href="image.jpg" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" id="lightbox"><img src="lightboxbutton.png"></a>`
And the script that goes with it:
    `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#lightbox').nivoLightbox();

}); </script>`